# Encountered "Could not contact localhost:8005" when running the Tomcat Service Script in Linux

Tags: tomcat7

I created a tomcat service in linux to be able to automatically run the tomcat. However I encountered an issue where when I startup the tomcat using the service, it throws error.

```
SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused.....
```

But when I check, the tomcat is running fine because I'm able to access my localhost:8080. Then when I call the service to stop, the tomcat doesn't stop.

My service script basically just call the startup.sh and shutdown.sh. I don't understand why when using the service script, there's error thrown on startup and it cannot shutdown. However, if I manually call the startup.sh and shutdown.sh, no issue is encountered.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

I'm using TOMCAT 7 btw.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the "tomcat service" of your Linux system does its own tricks?

Anyway: 
8005 is the default port on which Tomcat listens to shutdown requests. Did you change this? (It is at the very beginning of server.xml.)
The service seems to check this port to see if Tomcat is running. (While most people change the 8080 port, few change the 8005 port, so the service implementors might have considered this is always used.)